# LISP - Replace values in a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I have a list of nils **(NIL NIL NIL NIL)** and i need to add two X in place of the two first NILs, so it becomes **(X X NIL NIL)**.

I have the following code:

```
(cons x (cons x (cons (cdr '(NIL NIL NIL NIL))nil)))
```

But this way it returns

```
(X X (NIL NIL))
```

Those parenteses need to be removed, and i don't know how. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: This works for me: `(setf (first *NILS*) :hello)` => `(:HELLO NIL NIL NIL)
`.

Comment: Lisp objects don't have parentheses; cons-cell-based objects just print that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a list to the first argument of `cons` then you are making a **nested** list. First lets say we make your initial list and the symbol `x` variables:

```
(defparameter *nils* '(nil nil nil nil))
*nils* ; ==> (nil nil nil nil)

(defparameter *x* 'x)
*x* ; ==> x
```

So how do we remove the two first. Well we can remove one with `(cdr *nils*)` so that means we can do it twice:

```
(cdr (cdr *nils*))
; ==> (nil nil)
```

Actually more than one `car` and `cdr` accessor has a shorthand upto 5 combinations. The shorthand is just starting with c and do the a/d's and end with r like this:

```
(cddr *nils*)
; ==> (nil nil)
```

Goodie, how do we add `*x*` in front of that? Well `cons` is defines as making an element in front of the second argument, thus `(cons *x* (cddr *nils*)) will make`(x nil nil)`. Again if you want to have another`*x*` in front of that you do the same with the firt result:

```
(cons *x* (cons *x* (cddr *nils*)))
; ==> (x x nil nil)
```

Using `list*` is like nested cons with a tail in the end. Thus the above code can be replaced with:

```
(list* *x* *x* (cddr *nils*))
; ==> (x x nil nil)
```

Now replacing the variables the expression that was stored as their value (substitution method):

```
(list* 'x 'x (cddr '(nil nil nil nil)))
; ==> (x x nil nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(list* X X (nthcdr 2 your-list))
```

The function NTHCDR returns the list with two first elements dropped & the function LIST* returns a new list appending specified items at the front. 
Observe that thus you obtain a new list rather then modify the original one.  If you really want to modify the original list (this may very well be a bad idea, proceed with caution), you can just make the assignment:

```
(setf (first your-list) 'X)
(setf (second your-list) 'X)
```

Modifying a list like this may result in modifications of seemingly unrelated data.  It is not compatible with the quoted literal list, anyway.